# squid3 access.log TCP_DENIED

Tags: logging, squid

In squid.conf we have some

> http_access deny ACL

catching a lot of connection attempts, so filling the access.log with TCP_DENIED lines.

It is normal behaviour, but too much verbose for us.
Is it possible to avoid logging these ones ?

best regards, Sala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access_log directive in squid.conf defines where and how access.log data is to be logged. This directive can be followed with a list of ACLs which all must match for any given request to be logged to that output.
http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/access_log/

You can do it like this:

```
 acl dontLog http_status 403
 access_log none dontLog
 access_log stdio:/var/log/squid/access.log squid
```

... or like this:

```
 acl dontLog http_status 403
 access_log stdio:/var/log/squid/access.log squid !dontLog
```

Comment: And what would be the configuration to send http_status 403 to another log? https://superuser.com/questions/1817646/how-to-configure-acl-http-status-403-in-squid-cache

Answer (score 2):

Each HTTP request made through proxy should be logged in the proxy access log with the appropriate status, so squid does log it. So - nope, there is no such way, if you intend to use squid only. You can, however, set a fifo socket with a reader application from it as a log file for squid, and then manipulate the squid log lines in your log reader application, aggregating them in any way you want.

Comment: I see, but we don't want to log the domains we block. For us there are policies about the web pages do users request and get, no others.

Comment: write your own logging module for squid then. default logging module fits 99% of squid users.